# JAVA how do we loop over set in reverse manner

Tags: java, set

How do we loop over Set in reverse order which is from last item to the first one.

for example:
from : A B C D
to   : D C B A

Comment: A `Set` doesn't have a specified order.  So it doesn't have a reverse order either.  Please provide us with a specific (code) example so that we can understand what you are asking.

Comment: (For a `HashSet` ... you can't because hash sets don't have a defined ordering.  For a `TreeSet` use `descendingIterator()`.)

Answer (score 1):

In hash-Set the order is not fix since its unordered collection, But then by converting the Set into List , you can use ListIterator as below

```
    //If you are using SET(unordered collection) ten convert to List first
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D"));
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(set);
    ListIterator<String> iterator =  list.listIterator(list.size());
    while(iterator.hasPrevious()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.previous());
    }   
    //For TreeSet
    TreeSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D"));
    Iterator<String> iterator2 = treeSet.descendingIterator();
    while(iterator2.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator2.next());
    }       
}
```

**Result may vary for first scenario because Set does not gaurentee any ordering, but it will print opposite of what your set have**

This will print for the second scenario (P.S in this case both have same result)

```
D
C
B
A
```

.